# Error Message " Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:jar is missing."

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I got the following error during build a spring boot project using Maven.

Error Message

" Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:jar is missing."

pom.xml file content are following

```
 <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version> 
    </parent>

    <!-- The following code this added to pom.xml file to import spring dependencies to Maven-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: I think the artifactId in the parent tag is wrong. You need to use `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>` there.

Comment: I would also recommend to use the most recent version of spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE apart from that Spring Boot 1.X is not supported anymore.